# Allowing webusers to create common paths on Google Maps (for car-pooling website)?

Tags: google-maps, routes, google-maps-api-3

For a car-pooling website, how can I get users to click on a Google Map and mark out the route that they follow, so that we may collate that data and identify which users can share a ride with others?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be better off using the [directions API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/directions/) to define point A & B, that way you can filter by destination first and then compare the sequence of latitude/longitude values to find correlation between the routes.

If you rely on users *drawing* their route on the map, you are going to have a harder time finding similarities between the routes. The directions API will return you a sequence of points that will match when the two routes merge.

**Edit**

If you want to have your users just draw lines on a map, you can use the [Polyline](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Polylines) overlay to achieve this. Handle the [click events](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#UIEvents) on the map and draw lines to each point.

Comment: yeah, I need to do exactly the latter... How can I get the users to draw out the routes? Subsequently, I want to see a 'density graph' of sorts at the different nodes - I dont need to calculate it precisely, but see it visually...

Answer (score 0):

The database you will need to build will be very heavy weight, and will need a lot of space to operate. Also the performance will be a major issue.

We have solved this problem using a engine called mCruiseOn. Soon we will be releasing a application iCruiseOn for carpooling. All you need to do is supply the apis with the ride information using a AddProvider (start gps, end gps, start time, end time) and use the Search api Search(start gps, end gps, radius at start, radius at end, start time, end time, time approximates) and it will return a list of car pool providers to you. You can use this also build android, iPhone applications.

No cost associated, build your product all the way, until 100 users. Visit www.mcruiseon.com, hope it helps.